# User configuration issue copy pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I created a pipeline to migrate a database from Azure SQL Database to Azure SQL Managed Instance.
I followed the steps in this link with few changes : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-bulk-copy-portal

> ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,
> 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
> Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Invalid
> object name 'DBDEV.dbo.User'.',
> Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Message=Invalid
> object name 'DBDEV.dbo.User'., Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,
> SqlErrorNumber=208, Class=16, ErrorCode=-2146232060, State=1,
> Errors=[{Class=16, Number=208, State=1, Message=Invalid object name
> 'DBDEV.dbo.User'.,},],'

the pipeline is working for an existing table but not for the other tables, even if I checked ***auto create table*** (see sink screenshot)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUwS2.png)

that's my precopy script

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DBDEV.[@{item().TABLE_SCHEMA}].[@{item().TABLE_NAME}]) TRUNCATE TABLE DBDEV.[@{item().TABLE_SCHEMA}].[@{item().TABLE_NAME}]
```

following the INPUT result of the run

```
{
    "source": {
        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
        "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT * FROM [db-dev].[dbo].[User]",
        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
        "partitionOption": "None"
    },
    "sink": {
        "type": "SqlMISink",
        "preCopyScript": "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DBDEV.[dbo].[User]) TRUNCATE TABLE DBDEV.[dbo].[User]",
        "writeBehavior": "insert",
        "sqlWriterUseTableLock": true,
        "tableOption": "autoCreate"
    },
    "enableStaging": false,
    "translator": {
        "type": "TabularTranslator",
        "typeConversion": true,
        "typeConversionSettings": {
            "allowDataTruncation": true,
            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the same scenario in my environment I am also getting same error.

[image]

If your database dose not contain ant table with such name, it will throw the error as not valid object name because query is not able to find that object in database. The error is getting because of this situation we are getting error database doesn't contain any table with name we provided in SQL script. after removing the SQL script and select auto create table option to create new table.

[image]

copy activity ran successfully.

[image]